# How to determine what is filtering port?

Tags: ports

I have a number of devices they are used in electric power SCADA system, which are connected to GSM routers to send the data to a server by means of two ports 2404 and 9002.
Some times the server can't read data from a device, then I used nmap tool to know the state of the device it gives me back that the port status is filtered. I use 8080 port to reboot the router remotely when it up and checked the ports they still filtered. Onetime I disconnected the device from the router and checked the ports in the router side only also they are filtered. When restarted the device ( electrical device ) and it respectively restarted the router then I check the ports they are open. 
Please I have two questions, first i want to determine exactly which is filtering the ports and affecting the other the router or the device. Secondly Is there is a way to check the ports in the router only or the device only, I suppose the suggestion of solution are applicable remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Port Status filtered means a firewall (or some kind of filter, network blocker) blocked the port. Basically your NMAP tool sent a SYNC request to router which either did not reply or replied with ICMP error.  Is there firewall? Are rules setup to allow this particular port. Most likely a statefull firewall blocks this request. Try to bypass firewall with option tcp flags SYN,FIN. Also investigate, if there is anything in between is filtering them.
For second question, try use the -sV, or -A option to get status of the ports.